# Google Maps API - InfoBubble won't close - close() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infobubble

I'm working with an Google Maps [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/). Everything works great except the `close()` function. Previously I used `InfoWindows` and there it was working.

BTW, Firebug reports no errors.

My InfoBubble looks like this:

```
var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      map: map,
      content: $('#balloon-container').html(),
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(areas[area].lat, areas[area].lng),
      shadowStyle: 1,
      padding: 0,
      borderRadius: 0,
      arrowSize: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#ccc',
      disableAutoPan: true,
      hideCloseButton: true,
      arrowPosition: 15,
      arrowStyle: 0
    });
```

If I execute the following command, all bubbles are just open:

```
infoBubble.open();
infoBubble.close();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `infoBubble.setMap(null)` ??

Comment: your solution of course... the funny thing is that in the infobubble source code they use `close()`...

Comment: LOL. In that case marking the answer would be helpful later for the community

Comment: there is a 6 minutes delay from stackoverflow :) Now i marked it, thanks again!